# In QField is filtering one field based on values in another no longer working?

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I am currently using *QField (offline) 1.7.8*, *QGIS 3.16.1* and *QField Sync 3.4.0* . QGIS is connected to a PostGIS database. I have created a form with a "Species" field that is filtered based on the values chosen in the "Genus" field. When I fill out the form in QGIS everything works, but when I try to use the same fields in QField in offline mode there is nothing, both fields are blank and give me no genera or species to choose from. In the past I have done this and QField worked flawlessly.

I am not sure if something has changed in QField and I need to do something different, or if this a bug. Has anyone else had this issue with recent versions of QField/Sync, or any suggestions for a solution?

**Some additional info I have one parent table and 2 child tables and the filtering issue is in a child table. Even when I open the "offline" project in QGIS that has been packaged for QField everything still works. The unfiltered lookup fields in the child table behave normally in QField. There must be something on QField's end causing the issue.